# Removing object from Iterator AFTER pressing a key

Tags: java, opengl, arraylist, iterator, lwjgl

Im trying to remove an object from my ArrayList, which is getting referred by the Iterator, so i can remove the object. But the thing is, that it doesn't work.

When a certain key "In this case, DOWN" is pressed while a Keyboard next is running, it has to remove the lastest object created in my 'balls' Arraylist.

I'm using LWJGL and OpenGL with this.

```
while(Keyboard.next()) {
if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_DOWN)) {
    Iterator<ball> theBall = balls.iterator();
    while (theBall.hasNext()) {
        theBall.remove();       
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work?

Comment: Well, i'm getting an error? Saying 'Source Not Found'.

Comment: When do you get that error? At compilation? When the program runs?

Comment: When i'm pressing the "Down" key.

Comment: It looks like you are polling if the key is being held down, vs a keypress event.

Comment: Everything about Keyboard / Keys, I have tested, nothing wrong there. So it's the Iterator with the while loop, that's the problem.

Comment: Have you tried what I suggest in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Remember you have to call `theBall.next();` in order to go to the next item. I don't see that in your code.

Comment: Well, I can't really figure out the way to use .next(); probably in my code, since i don't have to test. I just need to delete the latest object created in the list. Adding just the "theBall.next();" into the code, works. But destroys all of the objects, instead of just the latest.

Comment: Then you probably should do this in an `if`, not in a `while` loop that keeps going as long as you still have elements.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are iterating is not right, since you have to call next() for each iteration. But anyway, if you want to remove the last element of a list, you shouldn't loop, you should instead replace all that code with:

```
balls.remove(balls.size() - 1);
```